# vbs how to read registry path

Tags: vbscript, hta

I want to see with vbs, registry path. I have solution for reading the key.

```
 Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  WScript.Echo "ID = " _
           & wshShell.RegRead( "HKEY_USERS\key" )
```

Output is registry key string.

I want script which to show all paths in HKEY_USERS.

For example tree:

```
HKEY_USERS \
S-1-5-20_Classes
S-1-5-20
S-1-5-21
S-1-5-21-15325-362362362 (I want to output only this path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WMI [`StdRegProv.EnumKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods to list all subkeys under a specific registry key. For example:

```
Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
strComputer = "."

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
    & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = ""
objReg.EnumKey HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
  WScript.Echo subkey 
Next
```